# Cannot run multiple instances of a program in parallel on ubuntu in a virtualbox

Tags: permissions, mount, virtualbox, windows-10

I keep on my Windows laptop a virtual box running Ubuntu. Various Windows partitions are mounted and hence visible by the ubuntu virtual box. Linux software is actually stored on the windows file system, and perfectly executable within the virtualbox ubuntu.

That is until I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Now, Linux executables still run... BUT any attempt to start a second copy of a same program while one is already running fails. Actually, if I start a program - any program `prog` - in the background and I `ls -l /windows_path/wherever/prog`, the `x` flag has vanished (it comes back as soon as the running copy of prog has completed.) Thus, the failure to start several copies of `prog` in parallel is because the executable file is temporarily  labeled "not executable" after it is first launched, and attempts to start another copy before the running one finished returns "Permission denied." This happens to ANY executable, be it compiled or shell script. I actually wrote a shell script containing the instruction to `ls -l` itself, ... and, (after `chmod +x`) starting it, indeed, it depicts itself as NON EXECUTABLE, while running!? Asking the script to `chmod +x` itself fails.

Does anyone know what's going on here? This never happened with ubuntu 18 in the same good old Oracle VirtualBox, and there were no changes on the windows host (neither was it due to a VirtualBox update). Neither did I touch the `/etc/fstab` after the update, it still goes like:

```
D_DRIVE /media/sf_D_DRIVE vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,exec 0 0
E_DRIVE /media/sf_E_DRIVE vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,exec 0 0
```

Comment: Virtually all answers to your questions were in my original post."prog" may be ANY executable - bash, tcsh, ELF executable, perl, python, etc. Windows partitions are mounted as vboxsf, see above. I want two jobs "prog" to run in parallel on my one & only Ubuntu virtual box. It does not matter how I'd start them, from different terminals, or,by using queue management tools (GNU parallel). As soon as the first "prog" instance runs, the file is toggled non-executable, so the second run cannot even start. Once the first run is done, the prog file magically switches back to its "+x" mode.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like VirtualBox bug 20320 https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20320 which is supposed to be fixed in VBox version 6.1.22.  Upgrade both host and the Guest Additions, since it's a shared folders problem.

Comment: You were right - thank you, updating fixed the issue! I was lucky to get a bug fix right on time! Cheers!